# How to delete indentation, but keep text in-line with that above it?

Tags: spacing, indentation

Currently, I am formatting a document, and the section looks like so

[image: Incorrect Formatting]

with the following code

```
\hrule

\vspace{4mm}

\textbf{Publications}

\vspace{4mm}

Author, ``The World is Going to End in a Month and I Don't Know What to Do, Journal of the Mayans, 123: 456-789, November 2012.

\vspace{4mm}

Author, ``The World is Going to End in a Month and I Don't Know What to Do,'' Journal of the Mayans, 123: 456-789, November 2012.

\vspace{4mm}

Author, ``The World is Going to End in a Month and I Don't Know What to Do,'' Journal of the Mayans, 123: 456-789, November 2012.

----------------
```

However, what I want is for the "Author" to stay in the same place, but the next line to line up with it.  When I try \noindent or a command alike, it causes the first line to move to the left, not the second to move to the right.

How can I set it so it indents how I would like, correctly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are you trying to do a bibliography by hand?

Comment: Thanks!  No, I am switching a CV from Word to LaTeX for my boss, but there are also a lot of different types of documents I have to put inside this section, so I don't think a bibliography will work how I want it to.

Comment: `biblatex` is fairly customisable. This being said, writing `\begin{minipage{\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent} \setlength\parindent{0pt} Author, ....... \end{minipage}` should do what you want.

Comment: You might, within a local group, `\setlength\leftskip{\parindent}`.  Be sure to follow the last entry in the list with a blank line.  The local group (delimited by either `{...}` or `\begingroup ... \endgroup`) is used so that when the next section starts, the indentation is disabled and the original left margin is restored.